# Android MediaPlayer white screen flash

Tags: android, animation, video, android-mediaplayer

My app displays an activity allowing the user to touch up to five points on a graphic, each of which displays a different animation of the graphic. The animations are provided by showing a .mp4 file using a MediaPlayer.

My hang-up comes when the animations plays. There is a brief white screen shown before the .mp4 starts to play. I have tried a few methods to show the video, all of which are based around MediaPlayer: VideoView, SurfaceView, and TextureView.

The most typically suggested answer to this problem is to show a View behind whichever View is used by MediaPlayer to display it's video which contains a background drawn from the first frame of the video. Before the video starts playing, it's suggested to make the video's View visible and to hide the background image View. However these methods are not relevant because they are based on MediaPlayer; the brief white screen remains.

Here is my basic setup:

AnimationLauncherFragment containing a RelativeLayout whose background is set to the first frame of the animations along 5 transparent buttons. Each button has an OnClickListener which replaces the AnimationLauncherFragment with an AnimationFragment.

AnimationFragment contains a TextureView and implements TextureView.OnSurfaceListener and MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener. When the surface is available, the callback onSurfaceTextureAvailable() gets run. Here is my implementation:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_animationlauncher, container, false);

    textureView = (TextureView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.animation);
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.bdleft);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    //also calls an OnAnimationCompleteListener to notify the Activity
      //that the animation is complete so it can pop the backstack
}
```

I have done some research into what causes the white screen, starting with LogCat output:

```
01-09 11:02:27.378    8086-8086/com.turbogunhawk.android.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
01-09 11:02:27.658    8086-8086/com.turbogunhawk.android.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
```

When the MediaPlayer gets created, it calls setVideoSurfaceTexture twices before starting the video, once for the method .setDataSource() and once for .setSurface(). Googling around brings me to [this](http://diousk.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-40-ice-cream-sandwich-media.html) helpful blog post, where I find an explaination of how MediaPlayers get created:

> After setVideoSource and setAudioSource, now MediaPlayerService will
>   allocate the SurfaceTexture for future video rendering (connect to
>   surfaceflinger)
>
> In Media Framework:android_src\framework\basemedia\libmediaplayerservice\MediaPlayerService.cpp

```
status_t MediaPlayerService::Client::setVideoSurfaceTexture(const sp& surfaceTexture) {
    LOGV("[%d] setVideoSurfaceTexture(%p)", mConnId, surfaceTexture.get());
    sp p = getPlayer();
    sp anw;
    if (surfaceTexture != NULL) {
        anw = new SurfaceTextureClient(surfaceTexture);
        status_t err = native_window_api_connect(anw.get(), NATIVE_WINDOW_API_MEDIA);
    }

    status_t err = p->setVideoSurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture);
    return err;
}
```

My guess is that the white flash is caused by the SurfaceTexture allocated when the MediaPlayer gets created, which is subsequently thrown away or replaced by the SurfaceTexture belonging to the View which is actually shown.

My question then is how to seamlessly display a video when the user clicks a touch point. Is there an alternative to MediaPlayer/MediaPlayerService for showing videos?

Comment: What version(s) of Android do you need to support?

Comment: Android SDK 14 and over.

Comment: Is this issue fixeD?